# Javascript: Values of array disappear after referring to it from other function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently try to build a form with javascript which has two functionalities:

1) Adding elements dynamically to a list

2) Identify through a button click a certain element (e.g. with the highest value)

See (wanted to add pictures directly to my post, but I am lacking StackOverflow reputation - so here are they as links):
https://i.ibb.co/KxvV5Ph/Bildschirmfoto-2019-11-03-um-19-12-51.png

First functionality works fine (see above, added installations). The second doesnt. My plan was the following:

1) When an element gets added to the list I also push it as an object of the class "installation" to the array installations = []

2) When I click on "Identify Longest Duration" I iterate through a map function over the installations array (and output the highest value as an alert).

Unfortunately, the installations array is empty when I call it from another function.

1. Get values from form

```
var instStorage = document.getElementById("instStorage");
var instMasse = document.getElementById("instMasse");
var instPrice = document.getElementById("instPrice");
var instDischarge = document.getElementById("instDischarge");
const installations = [] ;  // empty installations array
```

2. Adding values to DOM, Calling another function to add values to installations array

```
const createInstallation = () =>  {

    ... (working code to add vars from 1) to list element in DOM)... 
    addInstallation(); // calling another function to add installation to installations array

}
```

3. Class Definition of installation

```
class installation {
    constructor(storage, masse, price, discharge) {
        this.storage = storage;
        this.masse = masse;
        this.price = price;
        this.discharge = discharge; 
    }
    ... (getter functions here) ...

    summary = () => {
        return `Installation Specs: Storage ${this.getStorage()}, 
        Mass ${this.getMasse()}, Price ${this.getPrice()} and Discharge 
        Rate
        ${this.getDischarge()}`;

    }

}
```

4. Adding installation to installations array

```
const addInstallation = () => {

    installations.push(new installation(instStorage, instMasse, instPrice, instDischarge));
    (...)

}
```

When I call for test purposes my summary function within the createInstallation() function (after calling addInstallation()) everything works fine; the first element of the installations array gets displayed:

```
alert(installations[0].summary());
```

See: 
https://i.ibb.co/Khc6R7r/Bildschirmfoto-2019-11-03-um-19-32-41.png

When I call the summary function from the event listener of the "Identify Longest" button the installations array is suddenly empty, even though I added an element a second before (which should have been added to the installations array).

See:

https://i.ibb.co/80bTFWY/Bildschirmfoto-2019-11-03-um-19-36-48.png

I am afraid that's a problem of scope; but I don't see how to fix it. 
Help is appreciated :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Array is object, if you modify the object array in a function, that original array is modified. Debug your code again.

Comment: @ThanhTrung could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get values from form
>   `var instStorage = document.getElementById("instStorage");`

That is what is not happening. `getElementById()` gets you an element, by id. Not its value.
Assuming that `instStorage` and friends are `input` elements (which is not shown unfortunately), you may want to change the code to actually get their [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue):

```
var instStorage = document.getElementById("instStorage").value;
var instMasse = document.getElementById("instMasse").value;
var instPrice = document.getElementById("instPrice").value;
var instDischarge = document.getElementById("instDischarge").value;
```